# Why is this dictionary not emptied when the function is called again?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I was working on a dictionary when I noticed that if you have an empty dict as input of the function, after giving it input in the function the next time the function is called the dict isn't empty anymore. I have trouble explaining what I mean, so I hope the following piece of code explains what I mean:

```
>>> def test(input, dct={}):
...     dct[input] = 'test'
...     print dct 
... 
>>> test('a')
{'a': 'test'}
>>> test('b')
{'a': 'test', 'b': 'test'}
```

My question boils down to: why in this example script, when doing test('b'), does it print

```
{'a':'test', 'b':'test'}
```

instead of

```
{'b':test'}
```

Comment: See the "important warning" in the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).  We get this question at least once a week...

Comment: Sorry that I didn't find it, I didn't search for 'Least Astonishment in python' or 'The mutable default argument'

Comment: There are hundreds of questions along these lines on SO.  The fact that this comes up so often indicates that it seems to be indeed difficult to find, but I don't know how to improve the situation.

Comment: Problem is that this phenomenon isn't easy to search for the first time you come across it. I think it's a bit harsh marking this question down and closing it (4 close votes at time of writing).

Comment: @MattH: I think closing it is fine, since it is a duplicate.  And I didn't mean to "make it down".

Comment: Perhaps it's so hard to find because title variations are closed as duplicates.

Comment: @MattH: Closing a question doesn't mean it is deleted, so this can't be the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because here `dct={}` makes default value of `dct` always pointing to the same object, instead of creating an empty dictionary every time. This is a common pitfall Python programmers may fall into.

[This article](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) explains this problem in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Function arguments in python are only initialized once. If you want it to be per-call, just initialize it as an empty dict inside your function.